# How does os.listdir() performs on very large folders?

Tags: python, bigdata, listdir

I plan on getting a huge folder of data. The total size of the folder would be approximately `2TB` and it would be comprised of about 2 million files. I will need to perform some processing on those files (mainly removing 99% of them).

I anticipate some issues due to the size of the data. In particular, I would like to know if Python is able to list these files correctly using `os.listdir()` in a reasonable time.

For instance, I know from experience that in some cases, deleting huge folders like this one on Ubuntu can be painful.

Comment: `os.scandir()` might be a better option

Comment: [`scandir` is supposedly faster than `walk`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/), no idea about `listdir` though. Anyway, I doubt anyone will be able to give you a good answer here. I believe the best you can do is just try and see what works for you. `glob.glob` is another candidate.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think you're right, the best way to know is to test and see. But we never know, maybe someone has experience on that ;)

Comment: File systems don't perform well if there huge numbers of files in a folder. Somecare a bit better than other but still not great. Try to create a better structure. Maybe by creating a folder structure that bundles the files by their first few letters.

Comment: @DeepSpace `glob.iglob` also

Comment: @DeepSpace: `os.walk` is backed by `os.scandir` in modern Python, so it benefits from `scandir` (where `listdir` does not). It still has to load all the names in each directory into memory at once (so it doesn't save on memory), but it benefits from the free file type detection (it needs to separate files from directories, and `os.scandir` gives you that for free, `os.listdir` doesn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.scandir` was created [largely because of issues with using `os.listdir` on huge directories](https://bugs.python.org/issue11406), so I would expect `os.listdir` to suffer in the scenario you describe, where `os.scandir` should perform better, both because it can process the folders with lower memory consumption and because (typically) you benefit at least a little by avoiding per-entry `stat` calls (e.g. to distinguish files from directories).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're given those millions of files already in the form of huge folder, you may easily separate them when copying, for example, use first few characters of the file as a folder name, for example:

```
abcoweowiejr.jpg goes to abc/ folder
012574034539.jpg goes to 012/ folder
```

and so on... This way you never have to read a folder that has millions of files.